# Difference between the 3+ Google Analytics APIs

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What is the difference between Google Analytics Reporting API, Google Analytics API, and Google Analytics Data API? What I need is to report on the data for a 3rd party site/account, but it sounds like all 3 of these APIs are for reporting on data. Could you advise? I've been looking through their docs and they all still sound the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics hub is for big query.

[Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) -  Gives access to extract data from Universal analytics accounts

Google analytics api - is a little harder to nail down.  It almost sounds like it gives access to extract data and and configure google analytics data.  Which would imply that its [management api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) for for universal analytics [Google analytics admin api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1) and possibly the reporting api as well.

[Google analytics data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)  - used to extract data from Google analytics ga4 accounts

> What I need is to report on the data for a 3rd party site/account

Im not sure what you mean by this.  None of those are for sending data to google analytics.  To send data to google analytics.  you would use one of the [collection](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection) options.

Comment: No, I don't need to send data TO google analytics. I need to receive data FROM google analytics for a 3rd party's account and property and report on it.

So how is "Google analytics data API" and "reporting API" different? Both are extracting data from google analytics by what you and the doc describes?

Basically, I need to report on 3rd party GA data and I'm trying to figure out which API I should use for that.

Comment: You need to find out if they have a GA4 account or a UA account.   If its ga4 then you use the data api, if its an old UA account then you use the reporting api.